# gsub wrongly identifying [:cntrl:]-characters

Tags: r, string, utf-8

I have imported text from .csv which is encoded in UTF-8 - or so Excel tells me. Now, I have a specific line of text: `mystring="drück dir die Daumen"` and I suspect it has ASCII-control characters. So I use `gsub("[:cntrl:]", "XX", "Ich drück dir die Daumen")` and get `"dXXüXXk diXX die DaumeXX"`, which is wrong.
I tested whether the string actually is UTF-8 encoded by `Encoding(mystring)`, which actually gave me `UTF-8`.

This is relevant for me because I need to identify punctuation characters. But when I try to replace, for example, a `)` in a string (say, `"a) this is an enumeration"`), `gsub()` doesn't remove the bracket.

I fear that the problem may not be reproducible... Any help is still welcome.

Comment: That's the wrong regexp syntax.  You would need `"[[:cntrl:]]"`.